# Blazor Generic Form Object Handling, with GUIDs - Casting/Binding to InputText?

Tags: c#, forms, type-conversion, blazor, server-side-rendering

Using Server-Side Blazor [**GenericForm.razor**](https://github.com/meziantou/Meziantou.Framework/blob/ee664b6cf25ab0ae70ceaee55fcd3ef77c30dc4d/src/Meziantou.AspNetCore.Components/GenericForm.razor) and [**GenericFormField.cs**](https://github.com/meziantou/Meziantou.Framework/blob/ee664b6cf25ab0ae70ceaee55fcd3ef77c30dc4d/src/Meziantou.AspNetCore.Components/GenericFormField.cs) from [Meziantou](https://www.stackoverflow.com/users/2996339) to automatically generate form editors, models, fields from objects received from external API.

This works well, however, generating **InputText** components for object properties with type **GUID** fails (and so; casting values, binding, validation). Therefore, I need to break out distinct handling of guid properties.

---

I modified **GenericFormField.cs**, adding an additional ***GetEditorType*** case for Properties with **typeof(Guid)** to explicitly return **InputText** type for the form ***editorTemplate***:

```
if(property.PropertyType == typeof(Guid))
{
      return (typeof(InputText), null);
      //return (typeof(InputText), new[] { KeyValuePair.Create<string, object>("type", "string") });
}
```

Along with explicit **.ToString()** casts between object value and ***get/set***. Also attempting to eliminate ***ValueChanged*** invocation for **Guid** properties:

```
            public object Value
            {
                get
                {                
                    if(Property.PropertyType == typeof(Guid))
                    {
                        return Property.GetValue(Owner).ToString();
                    }                
                    return Property.GetValue(Owner);
                }
                set
                    {
                        if (Property.SetMethod != null && !Equals(Value, value))
                        {
                            Property.SetValue(Owner, value);
                            if (Property.PropertyType != typeof(Guid))
                            {
                                ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
```

Additionally nulling out ***FieldValidation*** for **Guid** properties:

```
            public RenderFragment? FieldValidationTemplate
            {
                get
                {
                    if (!_form.EnableFieldValidation)
                        return null;

                    if (Property.PropertyType == typeof(Guid))
                        return null;

                    ... ....
                }
```

And nulling ***changeHandler***, which is assigned as attribute in the editor **RenderFragment** builder:

```
                    var val = Value;
                    if (Property.PropertyType == typeof(Guid))
                    {
                        val = Value.ToString();
                        changeHandler = null;
                    }
... .... ...
                        builder.OpenComponent(0, componentType);
                        builder.AddAttribute(1, "Value", val);
                        builder.AddAttribute(2, "ValueChanged", changeHandler);
                        builder.AddAttribute(3, "ValueExpression", lambda);
                        builder.AddAttribute(4, "id", EditorId);
                        builder.AddAttribute(5, "class", _form.EditorClass);
                        builder.AddMultipleAttributes(6, additonalAttributes);
                        builder.CloseComponent();
```

Modifying the next ***ValueExpression*** attribute is where I do not understand what to do to map and maintain *guid|string* property value binding between the **GenericFormField TModel** and **GenericForm InputText** field?

```
      var access = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(Owner, typeof(TModel)), Property);
      var lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(PropertyType), access);

      var method = s_eventCallbackFactoryCreate.MakeGenericMethod(PropertyType);
var body = Expression.Assign(
                        Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(this),
                        nameof(Value)), 
                        Expression.Convert(changeHandlerParameter, typeof(object));
                    var changeHandlerLambda = Expression.Lambda(
                        typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(propertyType), 
                        body, 
                        changeHandlerParameter);

                    var changeHandler = method.Invoke(
                        EventCallback.Factory,
                        new object[] { this,
                                changeHandlerLambda.Compile() });
```

Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way?

For the **GenericForm.razor**, I implemented distinct/override pre and post set values on some fields regardless of the underlying model/object. Maybe a variant of this in the razor component itself would be better (though doesn't seem so)?

```
    private async Task PrePostInput(Dictionary<string,object> pairs)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in Model
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties())
        {
            if (pairs
                .ContainsKey(property.Name))
            {
                var value = pairs
                    .GetValueOrDefault(property.Name);
                property
                    .SetValue(Model, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Frankly, I'm out of my depth and have struggled to work it out, so really do appreciate direction towards the light!

Comment: You can check this commit https://github.com/meziantou/Meziantou.Framework/commit/9214909057aa42ffa5f4ae4c17c6230ae6311203. It adds the support for `Guid` and `Guid?`

Comment: Thank you so much @meziantou. This is perfect and has steered me out of the mess I got into! :) I don't seem to be able to accept this answer, yet?